# Restrict access to comments in WordPress using the plugin Restrict Content Pro

Tags: wordpress

I would like to ask if someone can help me with this question. I can't find anywhere how to do it.

I have a website with Wordpress as a CMS. I use the plugin Restrict Content Pro to restrict access to exclusive content.

I share the post in freemium mode.

And now the question:

How could I restrict access to post comments?

I guess through something in the php code, but I don't know how.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use this plugin myself, but just found a good looking tutorial. Apparently, you restrict access to comments in the same way that you restrict access to anything else: By only outputting it in the theme files when the user has access to it. For example, the TwentyTwentyOne theme has a file "comments.php", which starts like this:

```
/*
 * If the current post is protected by a password and
 * the visitor has not yet entered the password,
 * return early without loading the comments.
 */
if ( post_password_required() ) {
    return;
}

$twenty_twenty_one_comment_count = get_comments_number();
?>
```

You can easily add another check beneath the password check:

```
/**
 * Check if the user has access, don't output the comments if they don't.
 */
if ( !rcp_user_has_active_membership() ) {
    return;
}
```

Of course, instead of returning you can also output something along the lines of "get a membership to see the comments".

The [tutorial](https://help.ithemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049324614-Restricting-Content-in-Template-Files) I found lists different ways to check for a membership, a paid membership and more special checks.

Two more things:

- Be sure to check if there are other places where comments are displayed. That very much depends on how the WordPress theme is built.
- Don't just change the theme if it comes from an external source, e.g. if it might receive updates in the future. In that case create a child theme and make your changes there instead. You can read more about child themes in the [Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).